Good vs evil story: Guy who came back from heaven battles guy who came back from hell
This movie has one guy that is a family man who dies in a car accident, I think, goes to heaven and comes back to life and another man that is a devil worshiper, goes to hell and comes back to life. Both have a connection to the other now. They have vision things and are able to see through each others eyes, I think, too. Near the end the bad guy kidnaps the good guys daughter to lure him out and the movie ends with a battle. I saw it on netflix a year or two ago and really liked it but was never able to find it again. Don't know the year. It's in English, I think U.S.

Year? Country\language?

Dont know the year. in english. i think in the us.

Think you're right. Deleted my comment.

This is it!!!!! Thank you sooooo much.

You seem to be looking for Hideaway from 1995 with Jeff Goldblum and Alicia Silverstone:

Goldblum plays a man who dies in a car accident, only to be revived two hours later. After being revived, he experiences frightening visions. He begins to understand that he has become psychically connected to a [devil worshipping] serial killer, and that by cutting himself, he can actually induce the visions and see through the killer's eyes. Unfortunately, the vision works both ways, and the killer can also see through his eyes. 

The killer, like him, died and came back to life, and later kidnaps his daughter (played by Silverstone). Here's a preview:



